# Removing Helper Columns in Making Combinations

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a small tool that generates all the combinations of a set of items using binary patterns.  The tool works, but it now requires a "helper" column for each item. *(the tool requires no VBA)*

I need some help to remove the "helper" columns.

I put the items in the first row starting with **B1**. In **A2**, I enter:

```
=DEC2BIN(ROW()-1,COUNTA($1:$1))
```

and copy downwards. *(this makes the binary patterns)*

I fill the "helper" columns *(B through E)* by putting:

```
=--MID($A2,COLUMNS($A:A),1)
```

in **B2** and copying both across and downward.

Finally in **F2** I enter the array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($B2:$E2=1,$B$1:$E$1,""))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

As you can see, the formula is really easy.  It looks for the ***1***'s in columns **B** through **E** and joins the appropriate words from the first row.

I am trying to replace the `$B2:$E2=1` with some kind of `MID(A2)` function. *(this will eliminate the need for columns B, C, D, ...)*
What I have tried is the array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A2))),1)=1,$B$1:$E$1,""))
```

But this just yields blanks.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT#1:**

If I use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A2))),1)="1",$B$1:$E$1,""))
```

I get a large set of the items, unrelated to the binary pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array formula (CSE) will eliminate B:E, and is relatively easily expandable to handle more names.  It assumes you have the `TEXTJOIN` function (Office 365)

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX({"Larry";"Moe";"Curly";"Shep"},N(IF(1,N(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/MID(A2,{1,2,3,4},1)*{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}))))),""))
```

If permissible, you can replace the array constant containing the names with a vertical list of names.

[image]

**EDIT:** To make the formula more dynamic, enter the list of Names in some column, and NAME it `Names`, then you can use this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX(Names,
N(IF(1,N(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT(
"1:"&COUNTA(Names))),1)*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(
Names))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(Names)))))))),""))
```

Of course, you'd then change the A2 formula to:

```
=IFERROR(DEC2BIN(ROW()-1,COUNTA(Names)),"")
```

and fill down until you get blanks.

**EDIT2:**  Eliminating Column A, and with a named range named `Names`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX(Names,N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(
15,6,1/MID(IFERROR(DEC2BIN(ROW()-1,COUNTA(Names)),""),
ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(Names))),1)*ROW(INDIRECT(
"1:"&COUNTA(Names))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(Names))))))),""))
```

Comment: Thank you very Much!...........neat way to parse **A2**...........I am going to investigate using your formula and replacing **A2** with the `DEC2BIN()` formula itself..................thanks again!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent See edit for a more dynamic formula.  Haven't figure out about eliminating column A yet.

Comment: The update is BEAUTIFUL!..................thanks again...............I really do appreciate your help on a topic that may not interest most people.......................I am glad I resisted the temptation to stop and just use VBA

Comment: @Gary'sStudent And here is the version eliminating Column A also.   And I suppose VBA would have been quicker to develop, but sometimes the challenge of a formula solution is irresistible.

Answer (score 1):

This will manually pick up up and return, have to change the frozen values, but its limited to combine only 4 words, the formulas in column A produce a text based result.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(LEFT(A2,1)="1",$B$1,""),IF(MID(A2,2,1)="1",$C$1,""),IF(MID(A2,3,1)="1",$D$1,""),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="1",$E$1,""))
```